# Not loading images From Resource folder in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have strange behavior in my app. In My app i am using below code get images from resource folder..working fine at starting but if i test my app continuously one hour after that i am not getting any images from resource folder then in my all view coming without back ground image...

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"box_s3_landscape" ofType:@"png"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"box_s3_landscape" ofType:@"png"]]`

This line of code does not caches your Image.

try using `[UIImage imageNamed@""];`

Comment: Why would this make a difference? If it's not cached then surely it will just be loaded from disk again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in Simulator? The Resources/iphone directory should work fine. This is a simulator-only issue, which has been [resolved for 1.8.0](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-2833)